# count total rows date wise from last 7 days in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, database, fetch

I want to count the registered user from database for last 7 days includes date of today and  I am mentioning the structure is given below for understanding :-

```
reg_users
+----+---------------------+------+
| id | added-date           | name |
+----+---------------------+------+
| 1  | 2020-06-01 00:02:40  | john |
+----+---------------------+------+
| 2  | 2020-06-01 00:02:41  | sue  |
+----+---------------------+------+
| 3  | 2020-06-03 00:02:42  | fran |
+----+---------------------+------+
| 4  | 2020-06-04 00:02:40  | mark |
+----+---------------------+------+
| 5  | 2020-06-05 00:02:41  | tim  |
+----+---------------------+------+
```

now suppose How I count the total registered use date wise from last 7 days.. where I am considering today is `2020-06-07 [dd-mm-yyy]` and I want get result in array like `[2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]` here `2` because  2 user registered on `2020-06-01` then on `2020-06-02` no user resisted so `0`.

Please help me..

Comment: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reg_users WHERE added_date <= ". date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-7 day")) GROUP BY DATE(added_date)"

Comment: Its not working `$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE timestamp <= "2020-07-27", strtotime("-7 day") GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)');
    foreach($stmt as $row) {
        // if($row == '') {
        //     $totalTech = '0';
        // } else {
             $totalTech[] = $row;
        // }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this is what you're after?

```sql
select count(*) as total, DATE_FORMAT(your_date, '%y%m%d') as date_yyyymmdd from your_table group by date_yyyymmdd;
```

It will return you a result like

```
+-------+----------------+
| total |  date_yyyymmdd |
+-------+----------------+
|     1 |       20200727 |
|     0 |       20200726 |
|     3 |       20200725 |
+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: sir I use your code but it not working and error 'y' `$stmt = $con->prepare('select count(*) as total, DATE_FORMAT(date('y-m-d'), '%y%m%d') as date_yyyymmdd group by date_yyyymmdd;');
  $stmt->execute(); ` How I result gets in array of last seven days

Comment: You haven't escaped the single quote. It won't work to copy-paste it, you'll have to make it fit your code. As for putting the results in a single array I'd do that PHP-side rather than through an SQL statement.

Comment: I am not able to get result in array I used your code it bit works thank you but help in find array too `$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT count(*) AS total, DATE_FORMAT('27062020', '%d%m%y') AS added-date from reg_users group by added-date");
  $stmt->execute();

  while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
  {
      echo print_r($row['total']);
  }` result I am showing is `111121` ?